# Search for a String in 1000 files and each file size is 1GB

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop, grep

I am working on SunOS (which is slightly brain-dead). And below is the Disk Throughput for the above Solaris Machine-

```
bash-3.00$ iostat -d 1 10
    sd0           sd1           sd2           sd3
kps tps serv  kps tps serv  kps tps serv  kps tps serv
  0   0    0  551  16    8  553  16    8  554  16    8
  0   0    0  701  11   25    0   0    0  1148  17   33
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
  0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0
```

**Problem Statement**

I have around `1000 files` and each file is of the size of `1GB`. And I need to find a `String` in all these `1000 files` and also which files contains that particular String. I am working with `Hadoop File System` and all those `1000 files` are in Hadoop File System.

All the `1000 files` are under `real-time` folder, so If I do like this below, I will be getting all the `1000 files`. And I need to find which files contains a particular String.

```
bash-3.00$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/technology/b_dps/real-time
```

So for the above problem statement, I am using the below command that will find all the files which contains the particular string-

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/technology/b_dps/real-time | awk '{print $8}' | while read f; do hadoop fs -cat $f | grep cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c1 >/dev/null && echo $f; done
```

So in the above case it will find all the files which contains this string **cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c1**. And it is working fine for me and I am able to get the file names which contains the particular string.

**My Question is-**

But the problem with above command is, it is **very very slow**. So is there any way we can `parallelize` the above command or make the above command to search the files a lot faster?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If the files are large and the hit is early in the file, `grep -l pattern file` instead if `grep pattern file >/dev/null && echo file` will already offer a substantial optimization. `grep -q` will offer similar benefits.

Comment: so you are saying, I should do something like this `grep -l cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c1 >/dev/null` ?

Comment: If you have the input file name, `grep -l pattern file` will print the file name and quit as soon as it finds a match. If input is from a pipe, `grep -q pattern && print filename`. No redirection to `/dev/null` is necessary. This is presuming you have a `grep` with these option flags, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple MapReduce job to achieve this if you want. You don't actually need any reducers though, so the number of reducers would be set to zero. This way you can make use of the parallel processing power of MapReduce and chunk though the files much faster than a serial grep.

Just set up a Mapper that can be configured to search for the string you want. You will probably read in the files using the TextInputFormat, split the line and check for the values you are searching for. You can then write out the name of the current input file for the Mapper that matches.

**Update:**

To get going on this you could start with the standard word count example: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount. You can remove the Reducer and just modify the Mapper. It reads the input a line at a time where the line is contained in the value as a Text object. I dont know what format your data is, but you could even just convert the Text to a String and hardcode a .contains("") against that value to find the String you're searching for (for simplicity, not speed or best practice). You just need to workout which file the Mapper was processing when you get a hit and then write out the files name.

Comment: Thanks Binary for the comment, I am not that good in writing MapReduce jobs. Can you please help us out here? I can provide more details about the file structure if you need. By this I will be able to understand more.

Comment: I added some suggestions that i hope will help you along.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a hint from grep class. It comes with the distribution in the example folder.

./bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapred-examples-0.22.0.jar grep input output regex

For details source on the implementation of this class you can go to the directory. "src\examples\org\apache\hadoop\examples" that comes with the distribution

### So you can do this in your main class:

```
 Job searchjob = new Job(conf);    
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths("job Name", "input direcotory in hdfs");
      searchjob.setMapperClass(SearchMapper.class);    
      searchjob.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
      searchjob.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
```

---

**In your SearchMapper.class you can do this.**

```
   public void map(K key, Text value,
                      OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output,
                      Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
        String text = value.toString();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if(matcher.find()) {
          output.collect(key,value);
}
```

Comment: could you explain what OutputCollector is compared to Context ?
I have seen several mappers using Context and not this OutputCollector

Comment: Also I think you need to add the searchpattern - example: 
    
  
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<text to search for>");`
`Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);`

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1000 files, is there any reason to use a finely-grained parallelized technique? Why not just use xargs, or gnu parallel, and split the work over the files, instead of splitting the work within a file?

Also it looks like you are grepping a literal string (not a regex); you can use the -F grep flag to search for string literals, which may speed things up, depending on how grep is implemented/optimized.

I haven't worked with mapReduce specifically, so this post may or may not be on point.

Comment: If it has to be done in Unix, then what changes I need to make in our above command as you mentioned something about using `-F grep`. Can you modify my Unix command so that I can understand it more? That will help me to understand it.

Comment: grep -F cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c

Comment: `grep -F  cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c *`

or

`fgrep cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c *`

You need the type at the end - in this case wildcard ' * ' signifies, search in all files