# Using Hadoop to find files that contain a particular string

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have around `1000 files` and each file is of the size of `1GB`. And I need to find a String in all these `1000 files` and also which files contains that particular String. I am working with Hadoop File System and all those `1000 files` are in Hadoop File System.

All the `1000 files` are under real folder, so If I do like this below, I will be getting all the `1000 files`. And I need to find which files contains a particular String **hello** under real folder.

```
bash-3.00$ hadoop fs -ls /technology/dps/real
```

And this is my data structure in hdfs-

```
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '\29'
collection items terminated by ','
map keys terminated by ':'
stored as textfile
```

How I can write MapReduce jobs to do this particular problem so that I can find which files contains a particular string? Any simple example will be of great help to me.

**Update:-**

With the use of grep in Unix I can solve the above problem scenario, but it is very very slow and it takes lot of time to get the actual output-

```
hadoop fs -ls /technology/dps/real | awk '{print $8}' | while read f; do hadoop fs -cat $f | grep cec7051a1380a47a4497a107fecb84c1 >/dev/null && echo $f; done
```

So that is the reason I was looking for some MapReduce jobs to do this kind of problem...

Comment: Is the String you need to find part of the text contained inside the file or is it the file name?

Comment: I think OP means searching in file contents. Otherwise he would not mention file size.

Comment: I need to find the string inside all those 1000 files contents. And which files contains that particular String is my goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for a String in 1000 files and each file size is 1GB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732396/search-for-a-string-in-1000-files-and-each-file-size-is-1gb)

Comment: In that question, I am just trying to find Unix alternative to do that way not the MapReduce job and then somebody suggested me you can better in MapReduce job, so that is the reason I posted this as a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a grep-like program, which is easy to implement using [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/streaming.html) (the Hadoop Java API would work too):

First, write a mapper that outputs the name of the file being processed if the line being processed contains your search string.  I used Python, but any language would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

SEARCH_STRING = os.environ["SEARCH_STRING"]

for line in sys.stdin:
    if SEARCH_STRING in line.split():
        print os.environ["map_input_file"]
```

This code reads the search string from the `SEARCH_STRING` environmental variable.  Here, I split the input line and check whether the search string matches any of the splits; you could change this to perform a substring search or use regular expressions to check for matches.

Next, run a Hadoop streaming job using this mapper and no reducers:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar \
    -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0
    -input hdfs:///data \
    -mapper search.py \
    -file search.py \
    -output /search_results \
    -cmdenv SEARCH_STRING="Apache"
```

The output will be written in several parts; to obtain a list of matches, you can simply cat the files (provided they aren't too big):

```
$ bin/hadoop fs -cat /search_results/part-*
hdfs://localhost/data/CHANGES.txt
hdfs://localhost/data/CHANGES.txt
hdfs://localhost/data/ivy.xml   
hdfs://localhost/data/README.txt
...
```

Comment: Thanks Josh for the suggestion. The solution you provided, I was not able to understand, Can you please make it more clear so that I can understand and also I have no clue what should be the Mapper in this case as I am new to MapReduce jobs so that is the reason I was facing a lot of problem. Any working example basis on my problem scenario will help me to understand how this MapReduce thing work.

Comment: @rjchar: I'm using the Hadoop Streaming API, which lets me write mappers and reducers using shell scripts or other utilities.  In my answer, the Python program acts as the mapper.  If you're new to MapReduce, Google Code University has a nice [overview](https://code.google.com/edu/parallel/mapreduce-tutorial.html) of the MapReduce model , and the [Hadoop MapReduce Tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html) explains how to write MapReduce programs in Hadoop.

Comment: So the Python program you wrote, that's a Mapper? And I can run the example that you gave me directly on the hadoop cluster.. right? And also what does `-input` means here, it means the folder under which all the 1000 files are there?

Answer (score 1):

To get the filename you are currently processing, do:

```
((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName()
```

When you are searching your file record by record, when you see `hello`, emit the above path (and maybe the line or anything else).

Set the number of reducers to 0, they aren't doing anything here.

---

Does 'row format delimited' mean that lines are delimited by a newline? in which case `TextInputFormat` and `LineRecordReader` work fine here.

Comment: Thanks orangeoctopus for the suggestions. I am new to MapReduce world, so don't have that much clue on this. If you can give me simple example basis on my problem scenario that will work, then I can try that custom mapper with reducer set as zero to test it, then I will be able to understand more. It wiil be of great help to me.

Comment: Can you provide me some sample example basis on my scenario so that I can understand more. It will be of great help to me in understanding the custom Mapper and Reduce thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, though I'm not sure if it's an efficient way to go about it. Let me know if it works - I haven't tested it or anything.

You can use it like this: ***java SearchFiles /technology/dps/real hello*** making sure you run it from the appropriate directory of course.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: [search-dir] [search-string]");
            return;
        }
        File searchDir = new File(args[0]);
        String searchString = args[1];
        ArrayList<File> matches = checkFiles(searchDir.listFiles(), searchString, new ArrayList<File>());
        System.out.println("These files contain '" + searchString + "':");
        for (File file : matches) {
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<File> checkFiles(File[] files, String search, ArrayList<File> acc) throws IOException {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                checkFiles(file.listFiles(), search, acc);
            } else {
                if (fileContainsString(file, search)) {
                    acc.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }

    private static boolean fileContainsString(File file, String search) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(search)) {
                in.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are two parameters, this Java program takes? I guess..First parameter it takes is the folder which contains all those 1000 files and second parameter, it takes is the String you want to search? And also I have updated my question. Can you let me know this will be faster than the Unix grep? And also I am working with Hadoop cluster, so can I run this Java program as it is? Or I need to write some Custom Mapper and Reducer to do this problem?

Comment: Hold on... I'm updating it a bit.

Comment: This answer will not work with Hadoop. It is assuming local files, not HDFS files. Plus it would take forever.

Comment: I've never worked with Hadoop before, figured Java would work seeing as it's all cross-platform etc. No idea how I'd do this otherwise, but it would take ages yes. Also not faster than grep... ever.